# caption in picture goes above the picture

Tags: graphics, captions

I have a problem: I have some pictures & I want to have the captions underneath the picture. I have used \usepackage{graphicx} and for example the code looks like

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=4in]{roussos_book/figure_23skn.eps}
\textbf{\caption{Μήκος ευθυγράμμου τμήματος}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Is there something I have to add in order to make captions appear underneath?

EDIT

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,mathrsfs,enumerate}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{yhmath}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[innercaption ]{sidecap}

\allowdisplaybreaks


\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
\newcommand{\triangqed}{\begin{flushright}
$\blacktriangle$
\end{flushright}}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: by default the caption goes exactly where you put it (but should _never_ be inside `\textbf`)  if it is being moved to the top then some code you have not shown is moving it.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thanks! Either I remove the \textbf or not it remains above. Where should I look for the code that is probably moving the captions?

Comment: since you have given no information it is hard to guess, the float and caption packages have declarations that can automatically control caption position, It is best to always make a small complete test document and add it to the question then people can run it and test answers. If you simply take your code from above and add it to `article` class document then the caption will be after the image.

Comment: @David Carlisle I edited my question

Comment: well there you go `\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}`  without reading the manual I would guess that means caption position at top......

Comment: Thanks! (I'm stupid! I didn't look carefully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is for `\caption` not to be positioned at all, it just appears where you place it within the `figure`. However you have

```
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
```

so the `floatrow` package redefines `caption` to just save its argument, which is then typeset at a position specified by the `capposition` option to the package.

In this simple case you could not load the package at all, or you could load it with a different option.